# Disable wireless headphone notifications?

Tags: ipad, notifications, headphones, ipados

I don’t own a pair of wireless headphones but, someone I live with does. Sometimes when he’s trying to sync his headphones to his devices I get there really annoying popup notifications to connect them to my iPad. Is there a way to turn off the popup notifications for wireless headphones?

[image]